# Creating a persistent reverse SSH connection from remote server to home client

Tags: networking, server, ssh, cron, tunnel

I have a home client I would like to connect to over SSH from my remote Ubuntu server. currently I create a cron job that persistently calls out from my home client to my remote server.

So far I have tried: `ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 root@<server-ip> -p 2222` and `ssh -L 2222:localhost:22 root@<server-ip> -p 2222` in a cron job.

I listen on the server using `nc -lvnp 2222` and I get a connection message saying `Connection received on 104.136.5.228 63119 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8p1 Debian-1`

I have also tried using the private key of my server to login through SSH. From the client: `ssh-copy-id root@<server-ip>` and `ssh -i id_rsa root@<server-ip>`.

Server response: `root@<server-ip>: Permission denied (publickey).`

But a reverse shell does not present itself. Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys has correct permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a ssh connection to your home-host, you need a ssh daemon running on it:

```
# assuming that ssh server is already installed on home-host
home-host $ sudo systemctl start sshd
```

You can create a persistent reverse ssh tunnel between home and remote hosts with:

```
home-host $ ssh -Nf -R 2222:localhost:22  remote-host
```

`-Nf` will put ssh client to background without execute any command on server.

`-R 2222:localhost:22` will allocate a socket to listen at localhost:2222/tcp on remote-host. This socket will forward all packets to home-host:22/tcp via the secure connection established.

Now, connected in a terminal on remote-host, you can connect to ssh daemon running on home-host with:

```
remote-host $ ssh localhost -p 2222
```

Note that you can use this technique to connect to any network service running on home-host, not only sshd. For example, if you have a web server running on 80/tcp on home-host, it can be tunneled with:

```
home-host $ ssh -Nf -R 8080:localhost:80  remote-host
```

So, on remote-host, the magic happens with:

```
remote-host $ wget http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: Good answer! I would add also the `-T` option which disable pseudo-terminal allocation to the `ssh` command: `ssh -TNf ...`

Answer (score 3):

Here is such configuration from one of the servers that I maintain. The configuration uses systemd service which is created at the client side. Also it uses [`autossh`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/autossh.1.html), so as first step we need to install it.

```bsh
sudo apt install autossh
```

Then create SSH configuration file.

```bsh
sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/auto-ssh-systemd-hosts.conf
```

```bsh
Host reverse.server-name.com
    HostName 192.168.1.199
    IdentityFile /root/.ssh/server-name.com/id_rsa
    User User
    Port 2222
    LocalForward  22 127.0.0.1:2222
    RemoteForward 2222 127.0.0.1:22
    GatewayPorts yes
    Compression yes
```

- Note the SSH key is possession of the root user, because it will be the owner of the service.
- Don't forget to change the parameters *Host*, *HostName* and *IdentityFile*.
- Here is assumed the ssh-server at the both systems listen to the custom port 2222.

At this stage you should be able to:

```bsh
sudo ssh reverse.server-name.com     # or
sudo autossh reverse.server-name.com
```

Finally create the service.

```bsh
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/autossh-reverse-server-name.service
```

```
[Unit]
Description=Keeps an SSH tunnel to 'server-name.com' open
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -N -q -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" reverse.server-name.com
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -s KILL autossh
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- Replace *server-name.com* and *reverse.server-name.com* with the actual values.

Now enable and start the service.

```bsh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable autossh-reverse-server-name.service
sudo systemctl start autossh-reverse-server-name.service
```

In order to stop and disable the service.

```bsh
sudo systemctl stop autossh-reverse-server-name.service
sudo systemctl disable autossh-reverse-server-name.service
```

You can get the status or restart the service by the following commands.

```bsh
sudo systemctl status autossh-reverse-server-name.service
sudo systemctl restart autossh-reverse-server-name.service
```

The service will be restarted automatically if it hangs. On the other hand `autossh` will keep it alive much longer than `ssh`, because it also detects automatically the connection's failures.

References:

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html
- https://gist.github.com/thomasfr/9707568

---

Once the service is started you should be able to:

```bsh
user@server-name.com:~$ ssh localhost -p 22   # connect to the local-machine
```

```bsh
user@local-machine:~$ ssh localhost -p 22     # connect to server-name.com
```

Of course you will need to provide correct authentication data to the commands.